# How can I drill into an JSON object and read an array using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have a JSON file:

```
{
  "header": {
    "type": "esummary",
    "version": "0.3"
  },
  "result": {
    "uids": [
      "3021957",
      "3202827",
      "2507140",
      "1996085"
    ],
    "3021957": {
      "uid": "3021957",
      "source": "J Pharmacol Exp Ther",
      "authors": [
        {
          "name": "Smith PH",
          "authtype": "Author",
          "clusterid": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "Jones RA",
          "authtype": "Author",
          "clusterid": ""
        }
      ],
      "volume": "239",
      "issue": "2",
      "pages": "574-83",
      "articleids": [
        {
          "idtype": "pubmed",
          "idtypen": 1,
          "value": "3021957"
        },
        {
          "idtype": "eid",
          "idtypen": 8,
          "value": "3021957"
        }
      ]
    },
    "3202827": {},
    "2507140": {}
  }
}
```

And my code is

```
Dim j As JObject = JObject.Parse(respHTML)
For Each item As JProperty In j.Item("result")
    If item.Name = "uids" Then
        Continue For
    End If
    Dim itemObjects As JToken = item
    For Each i As JObject In itemObjects
        For Each p In i
            Debug.Print(p.Key.ToString & " = " & p.Value.ToString)

            If p.Key.ToString = "authors" Then
                ' Loop Authors to concatuate them with a comma
                ' need name, name, name

            End If
            If p.Key.ToString = "source" Then
                source = p.Value.ToString
            End If
            If p.Key.ToString = "title" Then
                title = p.Value.ToString
            End If
               
            If p.Key.ToString = "articleids" Then
                ' Loop articleids to find pubmed and pmc
                'need
                '  pubmed = p.Value.ToString
                '  pmc = p.Value.ToString

            End If
        Next
    Next
    Dim testData as string = authors + " " + title + " " + source
Next
```

The code works fine except I don't know how to drill into the `authors` array or the `articleids` array to get the items I need.  Do I build another loop or is there a better way to pull the data.  I've seen a couple of other answers about JSON and they talk about building a class, would that be faster? or just cleaner code?

Comment: Using the class to represent your json structure would both faster in terms of development effort and cleaner code.

Comment: It seems to me that the JSON is poorly structured. Instead of having keys which are UIDs, the UID should be a property of a `"result"`, and the `"result"` entities should be in an array. It will make it much simpler. If you copy the JSON in the question then, in Visual Studio, choose "Edit" -> "Paste Special" -> "Paste JSON as Classes" you will see why it is not currently an optimal structure.

Comment: I have no control over the structure.  It comes from an National Institute of Health web .  API  https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&&retmode=json&id=3021957,3202827,2507140,1996085

Comment: it may not be ideal but it can be represented simply enough with a `Header` object and a `Result` object. The result will contain an `Array` of UIDs and a `Dictionary` for each UIDs data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use loops to drill in, of course.  A shorter way is to use the [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) and [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) methods with [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query expressions to extract the data you want.  You can simplify your code to this:

```
Dim jo As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
For Each prop As JProperty In jo("result")
    If prop.Name = "uids" Then
        Continue For
    End If
    Dim item As JToken = prop.Value
    Dim source As String = item("source")
    Dim title As String = item("title")
    Dim authorNames As String = String.Join(", ", item.SelectTokens("authors[*].name"))
    Dim pubmedArticleId As String = item.SelectToken("articleids[?(@.idtype == 'pubmed')].value")
    Dim pmcArticleId As String = item.SelectToken("articleids[?(@.idtype == 'pmc')].value")

    ' Do whatever you need to do with the above strings
Next
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/urluvW

Comment: Awesome-- this is perfect  Thank you

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your Json data is malformed.
Said that, there is more faster ways to elaborate Json data than that you are using (I don’t want to mention your library ). However in relation with your question you can construct inherited classes or small function which helps you (if you aren’t agree to change library).
For example, below is a recoursive Function that gives you all nested nodes passing the root node and the node name (that you need to find children's inside) as parameter.
This is also an alternative to the valid existing response by Rogers.

```
    Dim jData As JObject = JObject.Parse(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\YouUser\Desktop\test.json"))
    Dim getNestedItemsByNodeName As Func(Of JToken, String, List(Of JObject)) = Function(element As JToken, name As String)

                                                                                    Dim ListOfObjs As List(Of JObject) = New List(Of JObject)
                                                                                    Select Case element.GetType
                                                                                        Case GetType(JProperty)
                                                                                            If DirectCast(element, JProperty).Name = name Then
                                                                                                For Each listAuth In element.Children(Of JArray)
                                                                                                    For Each a In listAuth
                                                                                                        ListOfObjs.Add(TryCast(a, JObject))
                                                                                                    Next
                                                                                                Next
                                                                                            End If
                                                                                    End Select

                                                                                    If element.Children.Count > 0 Then
                                                                                        For Each C In element.Children
                                                                                            Dim nestedChilds As List(Of JObject) = getNestedItemsByNodeName(C, name)
                                                                                            If nestedChilds IsNot Nothing AndAlso nestedChilds.Count > 0 Then
                                                                                                ListOfObjs.AddRange(nestedChilds)
                                                                                            End If
                                                                                        Next
                                                                                    End If

                                                                                    Return ListOfObjs

                                                                                End Function


    Dim authors As List(Of JObject) = getNestedItemsByNodeName(jData, "authors")

    For Each author As JObject In authors
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("name: {0}", author.Item("name")))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("authtype: {0}", author.Item("authtype")))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("clusterid: {0}", author.Item("clusterid")))
    Next
```